# Run a cell "in continuous" in a databricks notebook

Tags: python-3.x, azure-eventhub, azure-databricks

Since eventhubs receiver stops listening after a timeout without new event, I want to run a specific cell (paragraph) in a azure databricks notebook from another cell in the same notebook using python.
I need to run this cell every time it completes after a timeout. It's like simulating a continuous running.

Comment: Don't think you can run a cell from another notebook but you can have that cell in it's own notebook and run that.

Comment: Thank you @Jon, But I need to  run this cell every time it completes. It's like simulating a continuous running.

Comment: In the other notebook, do you need to run only a single cell, or the whole other notebook? Take a look at `%run` which lets you run an entire other notebook from another notebook.

Comment: @arboc7, I want to simulate a continuous running meaning that the cell must be re-run everytime it completes.
I tried to put it in another notebook in that notebook use %run to recall the previous one not but I challenged a cyclic issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I use a `while True` statement and in the statement I put the code I want to run. Thank you guys –

```py
currentMessage = receiver.receive(timeout=600)
while True:
   for event_data in currentMessage:
        .......
        .......
        .......
    currentMessage = receiver.receive(timeout=600)
    print("end processing after timeout")
```